# Authenticate with UserToken programmatically

Tags: nexus, restful-authentication

I've generated a UserToken in Nexus WebUI and want to use it in my program for authentication to prevent using plaintext.
Right now i use Basis Auth like that :

```
private String getCredentials (String user, String pass)
{
 String raw = user + ":" + pass;
 String bauth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(raw.getBytes());
 return bauth;
}

URLConnection urlconn = new URL("http://nexus/service/local/repositories/foo-snapshots/content/com/foo/foobar/maven-metadata.xml").openConnection();
urlconn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", getCredentials(user, pass));
```

What's the equivalent with usertoken ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user token is a drop in replacement for username and password, so just base64 encode the username and password bits of the token the same as you are currently doing for the real username and password.

Comment: Stupid me, didn't expect it's that easy ;-) Will try on monday when back@work